# git push to azure wesbite - each line ends with `[K`

Tags: git, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have a few websites hosted on azure, they are deployed via git push from inside teamcity. This works reasonably well. The oddity I've noticed is that each line in the push log ends with the text `[K`. Why is this and how can I get rid of it?

Example output:

```
[11:35:05]remote: Updating branch 'master'. [K
[11:35:05]remote: .... [K
[11:35:05]remote: Updating submodules. [K
[11:35:05]remote: Preparing deployment for commit id '54d9236271'. [K
[11:35:05]remote: Running custom deployment command... [K
[11:35:05]remote: Running deployment command... [K
```

Comment: If `[K` is preceded by an escape character, it's a "clear to end of line" in many terminal emulators.  Probably something is eating the escape character.  Exactly where it's coming from is another question though.

Comment: hm, I am using git push to web site from Git PoSH and don'T see this. Might it be how TeamCity interprets terminal messages from remote Git...